# How to make regex for 3 slashes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write regex for following
`students/ad34567-06c1-498c-9b15-cdbac695c1f2/data/sessions`

Where `students`, `data` and sessions should be exact match.

i have tried this
[students]\[a-z]\[a-z]\[a-z]

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: your regex should look something like: `students\/[a-z0-9\-]+\/data\/[a-z]+`. you can test this [here](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex, although your question is not clear to me.

```
^students\/([\w\-\d]+)\/data\/sessions$
```

Check here https://regex101.com/r/xnxwCX/1
you can grab the data in between students/, /data/session.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex `[students]\\[a-z]\\[a-z]\\[a-z]` you are trying to match with word `students` in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[students]` which will match one of the specified characters instead of matching the whole word.

To match a forward slash you have to use `\/` instead of `//`. `[a-z]` is specified without a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) and will match 1 character from a-z.

To match your example string you might use

`^students\/[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+\/data\/sessions$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Htiez/1)

This part `[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+` matches one or more times a lowercase character or a digit `[a-z0-9]+`

Following a non capturing group repeated one or more times that will match a hyphen followed by matching one or more times a lowercase character or a digit `(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+`

You might also use `[a-f0-9]` if your characters are a -f